# where is the threads window in vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ide

I'm trying to find the threads window in VS 2008 described [here](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/08/01/neat-new-multithreaded-debugging-features-in-vs-2008.aspx) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/MultithreadedDebuggingInVisualStudio2008.aspx), but I can't find it anywhere. I've looked in View and don't see anything remotely like this. This seems very useful. Thanks for any help

EDIT: yes i am debugging
EDIT: thanks, I found it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *are* debugging, right? It doesn't show up otherwise. Also, it may be docked along with some other window, so check that it's not embedded in a tab somewhere. And the menu is Debug->Windows->Threads. It lists a shortcut of Ctrl - Alt - H for me, but I'm not sure if that depends on which keybind set you've selected.