# No threads displayed in the Threads Debug Window

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, backgroundworker

I am trying to track my BackgroundWorker threads as described in [this article](http://devpinoy.org/blogs/jakelite/archive/2009/01/10/5-tips-on-debugging-multi-threaded-code-in-visual-studio-net.aspx) the Threads Debug Windows is empty:

[image]

And yes, [I'm debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799551/869501).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to pause your application first; the debugger will not display anything while your code is running.

You can either set a breakpoint and wait until it gets hit, or click the Pause button to break immediately.

Comment: Thank you! `Debug` > `Break All` did the trick. The question now is: How do I kill a **specific** thread for diagnostic purposes?